# RE: PostgreSQL function to purge records in batches

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to delete records that are over say, 3 years old but we're talking in excess of 5 million records. 
So I was thinking about running the delete in batches of say 10000, committing thereafter and looping through till there are no records left to delete. 
An example function on how I'm currently approaching this is as below. It's not ideal for large result sets unfortunately and rollbacks will be time costly. Suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delrecords()
    RETURNS VOID AS $$
    DECLARE
    p_pid del_cursor_result.p_id%TYPE;
    p_cid del_cursor_result.c_id%TYPE;
    pcCursor CURSOR FOR
          SELECT
            P.PID, C.CID FROM mytab1 P
          INNER JOIN
          mytab2 AS C ON
            P.PID=C.PID
          WHERE
          (now()::date - c.my_date::date)/365 > 3
    BEGIN
    OPEN pcCursor;
      LOOP
      FETCH pcCursor INTO p_pid,p_cid;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
         DELETE FROM mytab3 WHERE pid = p_pid and cid = p_cid;
         DELETE FROM mytab4 WHERE pid = p_pid and cid = p_cid;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE pcCursor;

  END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: "*rollbacks will be time costly*"  - no they won't. A rollback in Postgres is extremely cheap. You are probably confusing that with Oracle.

Comment: What he said...  read up on the MVCC.  You don't want to mimic the procedure you've listed above.  Just be sure your autovacuum is set up.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name .. I probably need to test the PostgreSQL rollback aspect but yes like you said it probably is cheap since there no concept of UNDO segments in PostresSQL. So, now just wondering if I have 20 million records returned in the cursor then part of me is unsure how performant that would be as is as opposed to batching the id's up

Comment: I don't see the reason for a loop in the first place. Doing a `delete ... where pid in (...)` will be a lot faster.